# Docking station compatibility

Tags: compatibility, docking-station

I'm using **HP nc8430** with **advanced docking station** EA489AA#ABA. After 6 years of upgrading my notebook I've come to an end and am now considering an **HP EliteBook 8560w/8570w** notebook that also supports docking station connection.

AFAIK all these devices use the very same proprietary docking connector so I expect it should be possible to connect a newer machine to my existing dock, but I'm not sure about power requirements.

My station supports (AFAIK) 135W of power. I haven't installed any additional disk/other drive into its expansion slots, so all the juice is available to connected machine. And according to official HP hardware there's a 120W official power unit that can supposedly power this notebook. Which gets me to conclude that my docking station should provide enough juice to it.

### The main question then

If you have access to EA489AA docking station and 85x0w notebook can you please confirm that newer notebook model can be connected to older docking station and that it works?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work, not the power requirements, but the docking connector size changed. 
I have the same issue with switching between the 84xx series and 856x and 857x series